# Best way to remove JSON object from JSON object

Tags: android, json

Assuming that I have a JSONObject

```
{
    "poll_answers":{
        "213":{
            "poll_answer_text":"Black",
            "poll_answer_id":"213"
        },
        "214":{
            "poll_answer_text":"White",
            "poll_answer_id":"214"
        },
        "218":{
            "poll_answer_text":"Colorful",
            "poll_answer_id":"218"
        }
    }
}
```

what is the most relevant/best way to remove** a JSONObject with key "214" (for example) since the android **remove** method returns the value previously mapped by the key but not the given object excluding the object I want to remove. So the solution should look like:

```
{
    "poll_answers":{
        "213":{
            "poll_answer_text":"Black",
            "poll_answer_id":"213"
        },
        "218":{
            "poll_answer_text":"Colorful",
            "poll_answer_id":"218"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `remove()` method is what you want -- however, you have to navigate in one level deeper since it's contained within another `JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("your json string");
object.getJSONObject("poll_answers").remove("214");
```

Comment: No offense here, but what if I wanted to remove the object `poll_answers` ? The object received would be `{"213":{"poll_answer_text":"Black","poll_answer_id":"213"},"218":{"poll_answer_text":"Colorful","poll_answer_id":"218"}}` but what I wanted was empty object `{}`. Should I use loops to achieve that? Thx

Comment: If you wanted to remove `poll_answers`, you would just use `object.remove("poll_answers")`. You can only remove direct children of the object you're referencing.